# Multiple onload functions in separate divs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

currently in a course for HTML5 canvas, I'm trying to keep it nice and neat, but I'm not super versed in JS, I've got the basics, and I see some others have had the same question, but I could not get those solutions to work for me. So I was hoping someone could explain using eventListener as it would apply to my situation. Note: It skips parts 3 & 4 because I've not yet figured them out, I'm supposed to draw a 5-pointed start and an umbrella...UGH!!

/*******************************************

PART 1

Draw a rectangle starting at point (0 ,0)
That has a width of 50 px and a height of 100px
Set the color of the rectangle to a shade of blue.
Set the stroke color to black and the dimension of the stroke are the same as the rectangle.

Reminder - set the style first then draw.

********************************************/

//Draw Rectangle here

```
window.onload = function(){
            var myCanvas1 = document.getElementById("Canvas1");

            if(myCanvas1){
                //get context
                var ctx = myCanvas1.getContext("2d");

                if(ctx){
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#6363db";
                    ctx.lineWidth =5;

                    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 50, 100);
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 100);

                }

            }

        }
```

/*******************************************

PART 2

Draw a circle starting at point (50 ,50)
That has a radius of 20 px 
Set the color of the circle to a shade of red and set the alpha to .5
Set the stroke color to black and use a radius of 30px for this circle.

Reminder - set the style first then draw.
Use the arc method

********************************************/

//Draw Circle here

```
window.onload = function(){
            var myCanvas2 = document.getElementById("Canvas2");

            if (myCanvas2 && myCanvas2.getContext){
                var ctx = myCanvas2.getContext("2d");
                if (ctx){

                    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(204, 68, 68, 0.79)";
                    ctx.lineWidth =5;

                    var degrees = 360;
                    var radians = (degrees/180)*Math.PI;

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    //arc = (x, y, r, sA, eA, Clock/Counter)
                    ctx.arc(50, 50, 30, 0, radians);
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.stroke();


            }              
        }
}
```

/*******************************************

PART 5

Practice using text.
Draw text into your canvas.  It can say whatever you would like in any color.

********************************************/

//Draw text here

```
window.onload = function(){
            var myCanvas5 = document.getElementById("Canvas5");

            if (myCanvas5 && myCanvas5.getContext){
                var ctx = myCanvas5.getContext("2d");
                if (ctx){

                    var myString = "HELLO WORLD!!";  

                    ctx.font = "12pt Helvetica";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 157, 255, 0.79)";
                    ctx.fillText(myString, 25, 75);
                }
            }
        }
```

/*******************************

Simple HTML stuff

********************************/

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>HTML5 Canvas Drawing</h1>
<!-- PART 1

Draw a rectangle starting at point (0 ,0)
That has a width of 50 px and a height of 100px
Set the color of the rectangle to a shade of blue.
Set the stroke color to black and the dimension of the stroke are the same as the rectangle.

Reminder - set the style first then draw.-->
            <div id="part1">
                <h2>Part 1</h2>
                    <canvas id="Canvas1">
                        Sorry, your browser does not currently support HTML5 Canvas :(
                    </canvas>
            </div>
<!-- PART 2

Draw a circle starting at point (50 ,50)
That has a radius of 20 px 
Set the color of the circle to a shade of red and set the alpha to .5
Set the stroke color to black and use a radius of 30px for this circle.

Reminder - set the style first then draw.
Use the arc method-->

            <div id="part2">
                <h2>Part 2</h2>
                    <canvas id="Canvas2">
                        Sorry, your browser does not currently support HTML5 Canvas :(
                    </canvas>
            </div>

<!-- PART 3

Practice using Path drawing.
Create a 5-point star shaped pattern using the lineTo method.
Begin this shape at (100, 100)

Height and width and color are up to you.-->

            <div id="part3">
                <h2>Part 3</h2>
                    <canvas id="Canvas3">
                        Sorry, your browser does not currently support HTML5 Canvas :(
                    </canvas>

            </div>
<!-- PART 4

Practice drawing with Bezier curves.
Try drawing the top to an umbrella.
This should have one large arc (a half circle) on the top and scalloped edges on the bottom.

Position, height, width and color are your choice.
Do not overlap any other object.-->

            <div id="part4">
                <h2>Part 4</h2>
                    <canvas id="Canvas4">
                        Sorry, your browser does not currently support HTML5 Canvas :(
                    </canvas>

            </div>

<!-- PART 5

Practice using text.
Draw text into your canvas.  It can said whatever you would like in any color.-->

            <div id="part5">
                <h2>Part 5</h2>
                    <canvas id="Canvas5">
                        Sorry, your browser does not currently support HTML5 Canvas :(
                    </canvas>

            </div>

<!-- PART 6

Pixel manipulation.
Draw the image logo.png into the canvas in the following 3 ways.
1. The image exactly as it is.
2. Shrink the image by 50%
3. Slice a section of the logo out and draw that onto the canvas.

Reminder to use the drawImage method for all 3 of the ways.-->

            <div id="part6">
                <h2>Part 6</h2>
                    <canvas id="Canvas6">
                        Sorry, your browser does not currently support HTML5 Canvas :(
                    </canvas>
                <img id="logo" src="image/logo.png" width= "3300px" height="1088px">

            </div>

<!-- PART 7

Putting it all together. 

Using a combination of all the methods. 
Create a complex scene.
You must use at least 3 different methods.-->

            <div id="part7">
                <h2>Part 7</h2>
                    <canvas id="Canvas7">
                        Sorry, your browser does not currently support HTML5 Canvas :(
                    </canvas>

            </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="includes/modernizr.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [too long, didn't read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read).

Comment: SO isn't here to make your homework. Go ask your teacher, that's what he's paid for.

Comment: I just need to understand how to utilize the addEventListener instead of using window.onload, because obviously every onload you add gets overwritten by the next. It's an online class, and responses are slow, but thanks for your help.

Comment: the window object is a singleton global object, there should be only one onload event handler in your code, try to add all the canvas stuff one after another inside the window.onload function.

Comment: @Teo That's where that part confuses me. I don't know how to push each canvas into its respective div that way, and I figured the addEvenListener would be easier to work with.

Comment: well, the canvas related functions should all be synchronous, so just add the "window.onload = function() { //draw canvas 1 code ... // draw canvas 5 code }" one after another

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to draw a rectangle etc like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
      context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 7;
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Therein lies the problem, I could easily do this just adding each script within each DIV within the HTML file, but I was provided with an external JS file to use, and I don't know how to push each one into their separate DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

`window.addEventListener("load",functioname(),false)` should be basically the same.
EDIT: Just "load" in `.addEventListener`.